# What are independent events?

Tags: probability, independence

I know that if events $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A\cap B) = P(A).P(B)$.

Lets say I roll a die, and define the following events:

$x$ = Number is a multiple of $3 = \lbrace 3, 6\rbrace$

$y$ = Number is more than $3 = \lbrace 4, 5, 6\rbrace$

$z$ = Number is even  =  $\lbrace 2, 4, 6 \rbrace$

Therefore,

$P(x) * P(y)$: 0.166666666667

$P(x \cap y)$   : 0.166666666667

$P(x) * P(z)$ : 0.166666666667

$P(x \cap z)$    : 0.166666666667

$P(y) * P(z)$ : 0.25

$P(y \cap z)$    : 0.333333333333

My question is, why are $xy$ and $xz$ independent events but $yz$ is not? I had expected all combinations of events to be independent as neither events affect any other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to the Rob's [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-are-independent-events/3870#3870) the joint probability of two events in the discrete case can be decomposed as follows (See the wiki's definition for the [discrete case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Discrete_case)) :

$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B) P(B)$

Therefore, if the fact that we observe the event $B$ is **not** informative about the probability of our observing the event $A$ then it must be the case that:

$P(A|B) = P(A)$.

Thus, if the two variables are independent (i.e., the occurrence of one event does not tell us anything about the other event) then it must be the case that:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$

The crucial condition for independence of two events is: $P(A|B) = P(A)$. This condition is essentially stating that the "Probability of our observing event A over the unrestricted sample space = Probability of our observing the event A if the sample space is restricted to the set of possible outcomes compatible with the event B". Thus, the knowledge that the event B occurred has no information about the probability of observing the event A.

Comment: Thanks Rob and Srikant for your explanation. I understand independent events now. Just out of curiosity, if I were to draw the Venn Diagram of aforementioned events, are there any characteristics that I can look for to reliably identify independent events?

Comment: @Sara No, You cannot. Venn diagrams will only help you write down the formulas for the various possible relationships between the events (e.g., $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$. But, the diagram itself will not tell you anything about the probabilities of the events under consideration.

Comment: @Srikant: Noted. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: @Sara, if you look at a probability density function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function of the two events fxy then you will get a rectangular distribution if they are independent.

Comment: @Sara, the wiki is not perfect for the multivariable case. There are better sources. but a prob density function of 2 variable can be very interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I find it easiest to think of independence in terms of conditional probabilities: $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $P(Y|X)=P(Y)$ and $P(X|Y)=P(X)$. That is knowing one does not change the probability of the other. In this example,

\begin{aligned}
P(Y|X) &= P(Y \cap X) / P(X) = 1/2 = P(Y)\\
P(Y|Z) &= P(Y \cap Z) / P(Z) = 2/3 \ne P(Y)\\
P(Z|X) &= P(Z \cap X) / P(X) = 1/2 = P(Z)
\end{aligned}

So knowing $X$ does not affect the probability of either $Y$ or $Z$. But knowing $Z$ does affect the probability of $Y$.